# traceback.print_exc() python question

Tags: python, exception

I am using the following line of code in IDLE to print out my traceback in an eception:

traceback.print_exc()

For some reason I get the red text error message, but then it is followed by a blue text of "None".

Not sure what that None is about, any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`print_exc()` doesn't return anything, which in Python is actually returning `None`.  Looks like IDLE is showing you the `None` it returned.

Comment: ok.. so I was running the funtcion and printing it, I now have stopped printing it and it works well... thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 7):

`print_exc()` prints formatted exception to stderr.  If you need string value, call `format_exc()`

Comment: How can I print it to stderr instead?

Comment: `print_exc` prints to `stderr` not `stdout`. This caused confusion on another post today, so fixing would be good.