# Does Python traceback.print_exc() prints to stdout or stderr?

Tags: python, exception

I've read some [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html), but I can't find where the print_exc function prints. So I searched some stack overflow, it says "`print_exc()` prints formatted exception to stdout". [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3419961/3096304)

I've been so confused.. In my opinion, that function should print to stderr because it's ERROR!.. What is right?

Comment: Read the docs more carefully: `print_exc` is shorthand for `print_exception(*sys.exc_info(), limit, file, chain)`. The doc for `print_exception` says: It is the same as `print_tb` except <something>. And the doc for `print_tb` says, by default prints to `sys.stderr;`

Comment: Then, I think that second link is wrong. Thank you so much, @OpDeCirkel !

Comment: I added a comment to the other post to reduce confusion in the future.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It prints to `stderr`, as can be seen from the following test:

```
$ cat test.py
try:
    raise IOError()
except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
     raise IOError()
IOError
$ python test.py > /dev/null
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
     raise IOError()
IOError
$ python test.py 2> /dev/null
$
```

Answer (score 7):

BTW you can also control it:

```
import traceback
import sys



try:
    raise Exception
except Exception as E:
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) states "If file is omitted or None, the output goes to sys.stderr; otherwise it should be an open file or file-like object to receive the output."
This means you can control how / where the output is printed.

```
with open(outFile) as fp
    print_exc(fp)
```

The above example will print to the file 'outFile'